# tensorboard error: A logdir must be specified

Tags: python, tensorboard

Under windows, I put the event file at `D:\logs`. Under Linux ,the event file is at `/home/czh/tenlen/improved_graph`. But as shown in the picture, it raised the `ValueError: A logdir must be specified`. 
Evenmore, if I just enter `...> tensorboard`
it gives rise to the same error.

I think something is wrong with this problem but not if it is specified. 
I hope you can help me.
[image: Error presentation under windows and linux]

Comment: You misspelt. It should be `--logdir` instead of `--lodir`